# How to get latest of many groups at once

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    language = models.TextField()
    # other stuff
```

And I want to group the `Foo`s by language, then get the latest one in each group. I haven't been able to figure out how to use django's `QuerySet` API to do this (honestly, I don't know how to do it in SQL either).  So for example:

```
pk | date   |    language
---+--------+------------------
1  | 1:00   |    python
2  | 1:30   |    python/django
3  | 1:45   |    haskell
4  | 2:15   |    python
5  | 2:45   |    haskell
```

I want to get something resembling this result:

```
{ 'python': 4, 'python/django': 2, 'haskell': 5 }
```

Where perhaps instead of numbers those are complete `Foo` objects.

Comment: Do you have a separate table for languages? In this case you probably would be able to pull those data using anotate() or something like that.

Comment: @Agonych, I don't see how it matters whether I have a table for languages.  Are you suggesting that I keep track of the latest `Foo` as a field in the language table?

Comment: No, but you would be able to pull out latest date for each record either with annotate(latest_date=Max('foos__date') (providing foos is many_to_many with Foo) or by using function like get_max_date() in Language model.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a raw query to solve your problems:

```
query = Foo.objects.raw('SELECT id, language, MAX(date) FROM sqltest_foo GROUP BY language;')
for foo in query:
    print foo.id, foo.language
```

Obs: I'm using SQLite syntax, but other SQL languages should be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Foo.objects.values('language').annotate(max_date=Max('date')).order_by()

Or do you actually need the ID of records with max date?

You might want to read this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: Yeah, I need the IDs / the records themselves.

Comment: You cannot quite get it in one query - because this model allows to have two records with the same values for 'language' and 'date' but with the different ID. My best guess would be do a query for each item in the result set to find it's actual ID.

Comment: The query itself is quite simple: SELECT `id`, max(`date`), `language` FROM foo group by `language` order by `language`;

Comment: The SQL query for this is crazy simple, I can't understand why the django orm makes it so incredibly difficult/impossible.  I am trying to solve this same problem and I'm basically down to using raw SQL or making way too many queries.